# Execute multiple UpdateOne in a single action with MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I have this code:

```
foreach (TestObj test in testObjsToStore)
{
    testCollection.UpdateOne(Builders<TestObj>.Filter.Eq(t => t.Key, test.Key),
                        Builders<TestObj>.Update.Set(t => t.Key, test.Key));
    testCollection.UpdateOne(Builders<TestObj>.Filter.Eq(t => t.Key, test.Key),
                        Builders<TestObj>.Update.AddToSetEach(t => t.Data, test.Data));
}
```

- *testCollection* is a MongoCollection
- *testObjsToStore* is a List of item

This works fine, but is very slow because testObjsToStore could contain a lot of elements. Does exist a way to make a single call to Mongo's Server with the list of update action to process all in only one server request?

Comment: Have you looked at the C# driver's support for [bulk operations](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/getting_started/quick_tour/#bulk-writes)?